# How to remove blank date value after union

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a query which return values as

```
Col1     Col2     Date 1      Date 2    Date 3

A         B        1-Jan        
A         B                   3-Feb 
A         B                             5-Dec
```

I want to show a single record as

```
Col 1   Col2  Date1   Date2    Date3


A       B    1-Jan    1-Aug    5-July
```

I have tried using 3 union statements 1st with col1,col2, date1 and (cast null as date) as Date2 and (cast null as date) as date 3 and 2nd with (cast null as date) as date1 and Date2 and (cast null as date) as date 3 , 3rd with (cast null as date) as date1 and (cast null as date) as Date2 and  date 3

The union result set doesn't return me the desired output. The null date value still appears

Could you please help ?

Thanks !

Regards,
Shantanu

Comment: Paste your full oracle query.

Comment: group by col1,col2 should do this

Comment: How do you arrive at August 1st from February 3rd? or at July 5th from December 5th?

Comment: Select Col1, Col2, DAte 1,Date 2,Date 3

from 

(
Query : 
Select Col1, Col2, Date 1,cast(null as date) as Date 2,cast(null as date) as Date 3

Union

Select Col1, Col2, cast(null as date) as Date 1,Date 2,cast(null as date)as Date 3

Union

Select Col1, Col2, cast(null as date) as Date 1,cast(null as date)as Date 2, Date 3

)

Comment: Hi Rene, These dates are calculated dates based on a case statement. I would like to show a single row with date values and ignore the null date values appearing for date columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can try like this

```
select col1,col2,max(date1),max(date2),max(date3)
    from table 
    group by col1,col2;
```

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks for your help ! The sample I have posted is a general scenario. The query has 24 dimension columns and 5 calculated date columns. The dimension columns have multiple (same data) values and have calculated date against them. Due to null date values appearing for dimensional data (as specified in sample posted) in each date column duplicate records are appearing in the output.the I would like to create a SQL which will discard the null dates and show only a single row with all the dates from the date columns. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

At first place, your union query itself is wrong. Looking at the values in your sample data, you could simply use `MAX` to get the `date` and get rid of `NULL` values.

However, if you have more than one date value in the column, it will pick the max of those dates.

--Your union query, I build it using `WITH` cause,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'A' col1, 'B' col2, to_date('01-Jan','DD-Mon') date1, NULL date2, NULL date3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'A' col1, 'B' col2, NULL date1,     to_date('1-Aug','DD-Mon') date2, NULL date3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'A' col1, 'B' col2, NULL date1,     NULL date2, to_date('1-Aug','DD-Mon') date3 FROM dual)
  5     SELECT col1, col2, max(date1) date1, max(date2) date2, max(date3) date3 FROM DATA
  6  GROUP BY col1, col2
  7  /

C C DATE1     DATE2     DATE3
- - --------- --------- ---------
A B 01-JAN-14 01-AUG-14 01-AUG-14

SQL>
```

You just need to use the select query on your union query.